# Reduce delay when waking up the phone

Tags: performance

The delay between me pressing the power button and the phone actually waking up is annoying. Is there any way to optimize this?

Comment: Maybe you should give some more details about your phone and software(Rom etc..) I think for a lot of people this is no problem. What I mean it might be a Problem of your Device/ROM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a ROM supporting this, setting the CPU governor to "performance" will help a lot. This is not a practical solution though as this means that the CPU will always run at its maximum frequency which wastes a lot of energy.